# Parallel Invoke with AwaitAsync in WebApi blocking

Tags: c#, async-await

I've a webApi operation which executes 2 operations in || which internally invokes HttpClient sendAsync. If I apply debuggers and execute call, it works and returns. If I remove debuggers, both the async calls still work (checked in Fiddler) but caller of WebApi operation doesn't gets any response (using AdvanceRest chrome plugin). From the other threads, possibly I'm not using async/await correctly and related to ASP.NET synchronizationContext

```
//**WEB API Controller***
class SomeController 
{
     public HttpResponseMessage Get()
     {
         Client someClient = new Client();
         aResponse = new aResponse();
         bResponse = new bResponse();
         Parallel.Invoke(
         () => {aResponse = someClient.a()},
         () => {bResponse = someClient.b()});

        var response = {a=aResponse, b=bResponse};
        return Response.Create(OK, response}
     }

class SomeClient
{
    AResponse a()
    {
        var clientResponse = ClientMgr.Execute("url");  
        return new AResponse {HttpClientResponse = clientResponse.Result}
    }

    BResponse b()
    {
        var clientResponse = ClientMgr.Execute("url");  
        return new BResponse {HttpClientResponse = clientResponse.Result}
    }
}

//Utility CLASS
public class ClientMgr
{
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Execute(string url)
    {
        request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        //....request fill
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        client.dispose();
        return response;
    }
}

public class AResponse 
{
    HttpResponseMessage HttpClientResponse {get;set;}
    // Some other properties....
}
```

Why does operation returns response when I'm using breakpoints but as I soon as I remove them, it doesn't returns response?

Comment: What is `Execute`? You only have an `ExecuteFeed` method in your client manager.

Comment: Sorry.. was a typo... Its Execute only.

Comment: You aren't `await`ing for Execute's response anywhere. `Invoke` will *start* the asynchronous operation and complete immediately. Anyway, instead of `Parallel.Invoke` you could use `var results=await Task.WhenAll(someClient.a(),someClient.b(),...);`. BTW as it is the code won't compile. `Execute` returns a Task while `a` returns an `HttpResponseMessage`. I assume `a()` actually returns a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` as well

Comment: a() and b() return a custom response with some properties/data which is part of ExecuteFeed result.

Comment: Then why does `a()` and `b()` return `HttpResponseMessage`? Please fix your code example to an actual working example.

Comment: Updated.. It returns custom object but that object contains the HttpResponseMessage as was returns from HttpClient as well so that status code, Content and other properties can be passed back to caller for any investigation.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem *(other than the fact that the code you posted doesn't compile)* is that while you debug, the async operations actually complete. When you don't debug, they don't, and it returns a `Task<YourResponse>`, not the actual result of the `Task`.

In order for this to work, mark your method as `async` and use `Task.WhenAll` to asynchronously wait on both tasks:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync()
{
    Client someClient = new Client();
    var aTask = someClient.AAsync();
    var bTask = someClient.BAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(aTask, bTask);
    var response = { a = aTask.Result, b = bTask.Result };
    return Response.Create(OK, response}
}
```

Side note - You don't need to use `Paralle.Invoke` when you have IO bound operations. Those are redundant threads which will be blocked waiting for the IO's completion.

Comment: Thanks.. I'll try it and mark it as answer. 

However, Does It mean that in such situation Parallel.Invoke cannot be used? Also earlier in functions a() and be() before returning response I did clientResponse.Await() but that too didn't solve the problem (which I reckon ensures that task is through)...
Code doesn't compile as I mentioned earlier that its a pseudo :)

Comment: @helloworld When you post a question on SO, it should be a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not pseudo code. You can use `Parallel.Invoke`, but there is no reason to do so here. You need to `await` at the top of the call stack, using `await` inside `a()` and `b()` isn't enough.

Comment: I meant wait() not await inside a() and b().. Docs says that Wait() ensures tasks to wait until completion.. So I was expecting that even if a() and b() are not async (as I don't want them to be), still by forcing completion calling Wait() before returning response on the Task recevied from Execute(), they would ensure task execution and with that I can use Parallel Invoke to execute multiple such operations..

Comment: Do not use `Wait()` with async code. It will lead you to deadlocks.